# Get Object properties for sub(inherited) class - Excluding Base class properties

Tags: php, oop

I am using *PHP* and the funciton *get_object_vars()*

I have two classes

```
class A
{
    var $color = 'blue';
    var $wood = 'oak';
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

If we run the following code

```
$B = new B();
$B->website = 'stackoverflow';

var_dump(get_object_vars($B));
```

The output is

```
array(3) {
["color"]=>
string(4) "blue"
["wood"]=>
string(3) "oak"
["website"]=>
string(13) "stackoverflow"
}
```

My ideal output would be

```
array(1) {
["website"]=>
string(13) "stackoverflow"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Make $color and $wood private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PHP get_object_vars documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php): *"Gets the **accessible** **non-static properties** of the given object **according to scope**".*

In your code, the get_object_vars function is called from outside the object scope, so, you will see the **public** properties.

If the **scope** is the object himself (a call from inside the class instance) the private, protected or private properties are visible. (Except static properties)

So, if you need inherit $color and $wood in class B, you can declare them as ***protected***. If you don't want inheritance, declare both variables as private

Example:

```
class A
{
    protected $color = 'blue';
    protected $wood = 'oak';
}

class B extends A{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "SCOPE: Self object: ";
        var_dump("Color in B: " . $this->color);
        var_dump("Wood in B: " . $this->wood);
    }

    public function get_my_vars(){
        echo "SCOPE: Self object: ";
        echo "My vars";
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

$B = new B();
$B->website = 'stackoverflow';

echo "SCOPE: Outside object: B vars";
var_dump(get_object_vars($B));
$B->get_my_vars();

===============

Output:
SCOPE: Self object:
string 'Color in B: blue' (length=16)
string 'Wood in B: oak' (length=14)

SCOPE: Outside object: B vars
array (size=1)
  'website' => string 'stackoverflow' (length=13)

SCOPE: Self object: My vars
array (size=3)
  'color' => string 'blue' (length=4)
  'wood' => string 'oak' (length=3)
  'website' => string 'stackoverflow' (length=13)
```